# How to set borderRadius on a react-native modal?

Tags: android, react-native, modal-dialog, radius

I have a `react-native Modal`, I would like to render it with rounded corners like this:
[image: Modal example]

but if I define it like this:

```
 <Modal
       style={{
                borderTopLeftRadius: 10,
                borderTopRightRadius: 10,
                overflow: 'hidden',
            }}
```

nothing happens (at least on Android). I also tried to wrap the `Modal` with a `View` with the same style but with no more success.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution is to put a `View` inside the `Modal` (right after its declaration) with this style:

```
      <Modal>
          <View
            style={{
              borderTopLeftRadius: 10,
              borderTopRightRadius: 10,
              overflow: 'hidden',
            }}
          >
      </Modal>
```